# Is System Permission required for android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am   try to use **"android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED"** to run USSD code in android but it throw SecurityException even i am using required permission.

Code  :

```
            String encodedHash = Uri.encode("#");
            String ussd = "*141" + encodedHash;
            startActivityForResult(new Intent("android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED",
                    Uri.parse("tel:" + ussd)), 1);
```

AndroidManifest.xml :

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED"></uses-permission>
```

But still I am getting SecurityException

Exception :

```
   AndroidRuntime(2756): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED dat=tel:xxxxx cmp=com.android.phone/.PrivilegedOutgoingCallBroadcaster }from ProcessRecord{418f47c0 2756:com.usdrun/u0a10046} (pid=2756, uid=10046)requires android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED
```

I am not getting why it throw SecurityException.

Is "**android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED"** required  **System Permission** ?
 if yes than how can i use this in my Application ?

Answer (score 2):

> Is "android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED" required System Permission ?

Yes.

> if yes than how can i use this in my Application ?

Your app will need to be installed on the system partition (e.g., by a rooted device user) or signed with the same signing key that signed the rest of the firmware (e.g., by a device manufacturer or ROM modder).

Comment: Thanks, is there any link for reference.basically i want to run some USSD code without open dialer interface on my app.

Comment: @KrishnaRoy: "is there any link for reference" -- it's called "the Android source code". In particular, there is an `AndroidManifest.xml` file that defines all of the standard permissions: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Thanks CommonsWare, U means for this, i have to download the Android Sourece Code & make local setup on my system, than i am able to  add some standard permission & make some other changes ?.

Comment: @KrishnaRoy: No. Your app cannot hold `CALL_PRIVILEGED`, except by users of rooted devices (so they can install your app on the system partition). Or, if you wish to build your own ROM mod, your app can be part of that ROM mod.

Comment: Thanks CommonWare, I got your point, but apart from CALL_PRIVILEGED is there any another way to hide (run in background) Dialer interface at the time to run USSD code ?

Comment: @KrishnaRoy: I have no idea.

Comment: In my experience, just put the APP into /system/app can works fine if you use the AOSP Firmware. But It can't works fine on Miui which maybe modify by manufacturer.